# Is it possible to force GLSurfaceView portrait while other view change orientation with the device orientation?

Tags: android, opengl-es, orientation, android-orientation, glsurfaceview

We are development an video related `Android` App. And we need to support both portrait and landscape mode. Because the UI is veriy complex, so we want the UI element rotate. And because we draw local preview on the surface view using `opengl`, and it will become very complex if the `GLSurfaceView` rotate.

So we want to lock the `GLSurfaceView` orientation while keep the overall UI change change orientation when rotate the device. We have used the similar solution on iOS.

We only find the solution to force `Activity` `portrait` instead of only some `View` in the activity. So is it possible to do that? and how can we do that?

Comment: Did you manage to find a strategy that worked?